# exc_bad_access in C program

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

Okay, I know there is another question about "exc_bad_access" here, but that seems to deal with Objective-C and iPhone dev., while mine is only regular C.  I am new to C and am almost done with my first program until this error showed up.  I have been trying to figure it out for a couple of days and am going insane.  Any help is appreciated.
buggy function:

```
void edit (int i){
    char* z;
    char* y;
    char compare1[] = "on bobbin\b\b\b\b";
    char compare2[] = "not on bobbin";
    char compare3[] = "have\b\b\b\b\b\b";
    char compare4[] = "don't have";
    char wrapedit[] = "wrapped";
    char haveedit[] = "have";
    char editing[9];

    FILE *wrappedlist = fopen("../../wrapped", "r+");
    FILE *havelist = fopen("../../havelist", "r+");

    fseek(wrappedlist, i*14, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(havelist, i*11, SEEK_SET);

    printf("Edit? (y=yes, n=no)");
    fgets(z, 2, stdin);

    if ((*z=='y') && (strncmp(haveslist[i], compare4, (size_t)1) == 0)) {
        printf("Switch \"don't have\" to \"have\"? (y=yes, n=no)");
        fgets(y, 2, stdin);

        if (*y=='y') {
            fputs(compare3, havelist);
            fclose(wrappedlist);
            fclose(havelist);
            return;
        }
        else if(*y=='n'){
            fclose(wrappedlist);
            fclose(havelist);
            return;
        }
        printf("Invalid input.");
        return;
    }

    else if ((*z=='y') && (strncmp(haveslist[i], compare3, (size_t)1) == 0)) {
        fpurge(stdout);
        printf("Edit \"wrapped\" or \"have\"?");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(editing, 9, stdin);

        len = strlen(editing);
        editing[len-1]='\0';

        if (strcmp(editing, wrapedit)==0) {

        if (strncmp(wrapped[i], compare1, (size_t)1)==0) {

            printf("Switch \"on bobbin\" to \"not on bobbin\"? (y=yes, n=no)");
            fgets(y, 2, stdin);
            if (*y=='y') {

                fputs(compare2, wrappedlist);
                fclose(wrappedlist);
                fclose(havelist);
                return;
            }
            else if(*y=='n'){
                fclose(wrappedlist);
                fclose(havelist);
                return;
            }
        }
            else if(strncmp(wrapped[i], compare2, (size_t)1)==0){

                fpurge(stdout);
                printf("Switch \"not on bobbin\" to \"on bobbin\"? (y=yes, n=no)");
                fgets(y, 2, stdin);
                if (*y=='y') {

                    fwrite(compare1, (size_t)strlen(compare1), 1, wrappedlist);
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;
                }
                else if(*y=='n'){
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;
        }
                fpurge(stdout);
                printf("Invalid input.");
        }
            fpurge(stdout);
            printf("You don't want to edit wrapped apparently.");
            fclose(wrappedlist);
            fclose(havelist);
            return;
        }
        else if(strcmp(editing, haveedit)==0){

            if (strncmp(haveslist[i], compare3, 1) == 0){

                printf("Switch \"have\" to \"don't have\"? (y=yes, n=no)");
                fgets(y, 2, stdin);
                if (*y=='y') {
                    fputs(compare4, havelist);
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;
                }
                else if(*y=='n'){
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;
                }
                printf("Invalid input.");
            }
            else if(strncmp(haveslist[i], compare4, 1)==0){

                printf("Switch \"don't have\" to \"have\"? (y=yes, n=no)");
                fgets(y, 2, stdin);
                if (*y=='y') {
                    fputs(compare3, havelist);
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;
                }
                else if(*y=='n'){
                    fclose(wrappedlist);
                    fclose(havelist);
                    return;             
            }
        }
            printf("Invalid input.");
        }
            printf("Not editing.");

        fclose(wrappedlist);
        fclose(havelist);

        return;
    }
    else if(*z=='n'){
        fclose(wrappedlist);
        fclose(havelist);
        return;
    }

    printf("Invalid entry");
    fclose(havelist);
    fclose(wrappedlist);
    return;
}
```

I can input a char to the fgets after the "Edit?" prompt, but then I get the exc_bad_access error.  Please help, thanks.code:

Comment: Please, please, please, don't send full code. We don't want to read it all. If you could narrow down the issue and only send relevant code, we'd be in better position to help you.

Comment: Better yet, send the full code, but tell us which lines are the ones that are important. Sometimes seeing the full code can help pin things down too.

Answer (score 8):

It happens because your pointers point to no memory.

```
char* z; // pointer points nowhere
/* snip */
fgets(z, 2, stdin); // writing to pointer that points nowhere: boom!
```

This tries to put into `z` the two next characters from `stdin`. However, `z` points to nowhere useful. You need it to point to existing memory: declaring a pointer alone isn't enough to get memory next to it.

You probably want a buffer of 2 characters for it:

```
char z[2];
```

With this code, `z` will be a pointer to enough memory for 2 characters. (In C, an array can be passed wherever a pointer is expected.)

I didn't look too far into your code, but you'll have the same problem for `y`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated any memory for `z` or `y` **and** they're left uninitialized so `fgets` is writing to random addresses.